# how to achieve Editable Material-Ui Chips?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to achieve like this one [4th Example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips)! but for ReactJS - Material-ui

i've made something else by making 2 different fields over each other one(normal `input`) shown on focus to edit the text and other one(`chips container`) shown on blur to show to chips (not-editable).

so will it be on same way ? to put `input` inside each chip and show the `input` on click/ doubleClick ? and hide it onBlur ?

Comment: did u find the way?

Comment: @AsbarAli yes i made it my self a way to achieve that i will put the answer below.

Comment: When were you going to put the answer below?

Comment: @Tyler i've updated my answer below. (the code is bit old still in class component)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made it like this and working fine ,you can still edit the options as your needs, also a Link included at the end.

app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '#Jax #Tom #Zeus',
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const chips =
      value.length > 0
        ? value
            .trim()
            .split(' ')
            .map(x => {
              if (x.charAt(0) === '#') {
                return x.trim().slice(1);
              } else {
                return '';
              }
            })
            .filter(z => z.length > 0)
        : [];
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container" tabIndex="-1">
          <FormControl className="input">
            <InputLabel htmlFor="chips-input">Chips Input</InputLabel>
            <Input
              id="chips-input"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange('value')}
            />
          </FormControl>
          <ChipsContainer chips={chips} />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ChipsContainer.js

```
function Chips(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className="chip-input">
      <p>Focus blue box</p>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {props.chips.map((x, idx) => (
          <Chip
            icon={
              idx % 2 === 0 ? (
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDog} spin />
              ) : (
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCat} pulse />
              )
            }
            label={x}
            key={idx}
            className={classes.chip}
            color={idx % 2 === 0 ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is the CSS for it

```
.input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.chip-input {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  &:focus-within {
    .input {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .chip-input {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

[Custom Made Material-UI Chips 'Editable'](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/TITAN9389/editable-mui-chips/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23586922)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru ok thanks for the feedback , i've updated the answer and it should be fine i think now ,also provided kinda better link connected to my Repo. ( code is a bit old tho class based component)